# Python: Decode base64 multiple strings in a file

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I have a file like this:

```
cw==ZA==YQ==ZA==YQ==cw==ZA==YQ==cw==ZA==YQ==cw==ZA==YQ==cw==ZA==dA==ZQ==cw==dA==
```

It's an keybord input, coded with base64, and new I want to decode it
I try this by the code is stoping at first character decoded.

```
import base64

file = "my_file.txt"
fin = open(file, "rb")
binary_data = fin.read()
fin.close()
b64_data = base64.b64decode(binary_data)
b64_fname = "original_b64.txt"
fout = open(b64_fname, "w")
fout.write(b64_data)
fout.close
```

Any help is welcome. thanks

Comment: On a side note you are not actually closing the file

Comment: You forgot parentheses fout.close()

Comment: how did you encode the string?

Comment: thanks user4600699 and  Padraic Cunningham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you created your test input string yourself.

If I split your test input string in blocks of 4 characters and decode each one apart, I get the following:

```
>>> import base64
>>> s = 'cw==ZA==YQ==ZA==YQ==cw==ZA==YQ==cw==ZA==YQ==cw==ZA==YQ==cw==ZA==dA==ZQ==cw==dA=='
>>> ''.join(base64.b64decode(s[i:i+4]) for i in range(0, len(s), 4))

'sdadasdasdasdasdtest'
```

However, the correct base64 encoding of your test string `sdadasdasdasdasdtest` is:

```
>>> base64.b64encode('sdadasdasdasdasdtest')
'c2RhZGFzZGFzZGFzZGFzZHRlc3Q='
```

If you place this string in `my_file.txt` (and rewriting your code to be a bit more concise) then it all works.

```
import base64

with open("my_file.txt") as f, open("original_b64.txt", 'w') as g:
    encoded = f.read()
    decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
    g.write(decoded)
```